# Javascript scope error issue

Tags: javascript, timer, scope, closures, object-literal

I wrote this code that starts a timer. I fire a function that restarts the timer when it reaches 0. It works, but I get an error in the console that says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'restartTimer' of undefined. It has to do with this.restartTimer();

```js
timer = utility.math.surveyTimer({
    seconds: time,
    onUpdateStatus: function(remainingTime) {
        $(surveyTimerNode).text(remainingTime);
    },
    restartTimer: function() {
        window.TimerInterval = timer.start();
    },
    onCounterEnd: function() {
        if (utility.bool.isQuestionScreen()) {
            if (utility.bool.surveyWillLoop()) {
                data.setPersistentSurveyData('DSM_SURVEY_SCREENS', surveyScreens);
                data.setPersistentSurveyData('DSM_SURVEY_SCREEN_ORDER', surveyScreenOrder);
                
                tagData = data.getPersistentSurveyData('DSM_SURVEY_DATA');
                apiParam = api.helper.buildAPIParam('surveyTimeout', tagData);
                api.post.postToAPI(apiParam);
                
                parent.resetSurveyProgress();
                parent.moveToNextScreen();
                this.restartTimer();
            } else {
                parent.goToEndscreen();
            }
        }
    }
});
window.TimerInterval = timer.start();
```

No errors in JSLint, just errors on run. What's so bizarre is that it works, the timer does reset. How do I remove this error? 
Here's the function that actually does the timer counting:

```js
this.surveyTimer = function (options) {
    var timer,
        instance = this,
        minutes,
        secondsMinusMinutes,
        remainingTime,
        seconds = options.seconds || 30,
        updateStatus = options.onUpdateStatus || function () {
            return undefined;
        },
        counterEnd = options.onCounterEnd || function () {
            return undefined;
        };

    function zeroPad(n) {
        return (n < 10) ? ("0" + n) : n;
    }

    function decrementCounter() {
        minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
        secondsMinusMinutes = seconds - minutes * 60;
        remainingTime = minutes + ':' + zeroPad(secondsMinusMinutes);

        updateStatus(remainingTime);
        if (seconds === 0) {
            counterEnd();
            instance.stop();
        }
        seconds -= 1;
    }

    this.start = function () {
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = 0;
        seconds = options.seconds;
        timer = setInterval(decrementCounter, 1000);
        return timer;
    };

    this.stop = function () {
        clearInterval(timer);
    };
    return this;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but I think your use of `this` in your options object is not the `this` you think it is...

Try changing your implementation of surveyTimer, where it is currently:

```
counterEnd();
```

to:

```
counterEnd.call(options);
```

Comment: Thanks for the input Steve, but doing that prevents the timer from restarting.

Comment: When I add your code, no. The error goes away. But I assume that's because the method is not being called.